# nhibernate - restriction based on an expression

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I am using nHibernate Criteria and I'm stuck on something that seems like it should be really simple. in SQL it would be:

```
WHERE startPos + length > 17
```

(startPos and length are two columns on the table). Can anyone help me achieve this with nHibernate

Comment: I think it's not possible with criteria, unless you use an SQL expression. Use HQL or Linq instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way how to do that with Criteria in NHibernate:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<MyEntity>(); // C# MyEntity

criteria.Add(
  // add restriction
  Restrictions.Gt(
    // left part as a projection
    Projections.SqlProjection(
        "(startPos + length) as myAlias"
        , new[] {"myAlias"}
        , new IType[] {NHibernateUtil.Boolean} )
    // right part 
    , 17
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks that works great! - I haven't used projections before so I think I'll need a bit of time with the manual now to figure out how it actually works though :)

Comment: NHibernate is amazing tool. It can do really a lot for us. So do not hesitate and do dive in even more ;) Good luck with NHibernate